# How to surround portions of a tree with boxes

Tags: framed, labels, trees

I need to **group portions of a tree with boxes**, and additionally **label them**, e.g. put "W1" on the side of the box, or in the *top right* corner of the box.

The result I want to achieve is somewhat similar to the one in the following video:
http://youtu.be/B78RnoBFYOw?t=10m40s

or to this picture:

[image: desired result]

Note that the boxed subtrees *must* still refer to a node in the parent boxed subree. That is, I don't want a tree of boxes with trees inside, rather I want a **single tree with boxes around some portions of it**.

#### Edit:

Here is the code I use so far to create the tree

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node{
        $\forall{x}. P(x) \rightarrow Q(X)$\\
        $P(x) \rightarrow Q(x)$
    }
        child{ node{$\lnot P(a)$} }
        child{ node{$Q(a)$} 
            child{ node{other..} }
        };
\end{tikzpicture}
```

By the way, what would be the best way to add multiple lines of math into a  tree node? Right now, they are all on the same line.

Comment: How do you create your trees? Can you show us your code? For TikZ-based solution the `fit` library will help.

Comment: I've tried to use the qtree, embedded into fancybox (ovalbox), but it isn't working for me right now... I think TikZ could definitely come to the rescue

Comment: If you are using `qtree` anyway, why don't you use the `\qframesubtree` command it provides? That is, use `qtree` as the package rather than a `tikzpicture` environment.

Comment: Without a full minimal working example which shows how the picture is generated, we can't really answer properly here.